# Comment traduire « project roadmap » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

En gestion de projet, l'expression «Project roadmap­» réfère à une liste d'étapes ou de jalons positionnés dans le temps pour la livraison finale d'un projet. Elle est abondamment utilisée en anglais. J'utilise l'expression «Cahier de route» mais y a-t-il une meilleure traduction pour illustrer le concept?

Comment: De façon amusante les métaphore anglaises ont l'air plus routières que les françaises : roadmap (carte routière) et milestone (borne kilométrique) contre feuille de route et jalon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Salut. On a déjà une locution en français pour ça et elle est régulièrement utilisée dans mon travail : « Feuille de route ».

Par exemple, sous la forme : « NOTRE PROJET ÉPIQUE - Feuille de route ».

J'espère que cela te conviendra.

Answer (score 0):

complément à la [réponse initiale](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/31928/17649)

Le terme « feuille de route » convient parfaitement selon sa définition dans [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feuille_de_route) (reproduite ci-dessous);

> Dans le milieu informatique, l'anglicisme roadmap est plus souvent utilisé pour désigner la planification du développement/déploiement d'un logiciel.

Ce terme n'est cependant pas descriptif à un bien grand degré : on lui trouve cinq définitions dans l'article que lui consacre Wikipédia, certaines bien différentes des quatre restantes.

Comme la définition est très succincte, il y a la possibilité de l'utiliser elle-même et de traduire le concept « roadmap » par « **planification du développement** », ce qui fournit une terminologie directement explicative; bien sûr c'est une question de choix personnel.

exemple : **Notre projet : planification de son développement**

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour ce complément. En effet, je fais de la gestion de projet en informatique et le terme «planification du développement» pourrait convenir si ce n'est du fait que d'autres livrables tels que des campagnes numériques sont aussi à considérer, ce qui n'est pas uniquement du développement. Mais je retiens que je pourrai l'utiliser advenant le cas.

Comment: @Brac En vérifiant votre vocabulaire, qui m'est inconnu, j'ai découvert une autre possibilité : planification projet; le site où cela se trouve pourrait vous intéresser : https://www.manager-go.com/gestion-de-projet/glossaire/les-livrables

Comment: Merci de me partager ce lien. Très intéressant!